# Gnuplot: How to plot heat maps on three coordinate facets to visualize 4D data

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap, projection, 4d

I am new to Gnuplot and unfortunately have to start with a (for me) nontrivial problem. I have X-Y-Z-Temperature data. So I have for every spatial coordinate a temperature value. 
This comes somewhat closest
http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/contour-and-surface/

However, I would like to create a heat map (not contour) on the XY XZ and YZ plane to visualise the 4D data better (in the link it is just 3D).

So on each plane just a heat map using the same color code so that the temperatures can be compared.

Many thanks!

Toby

Answer (score 1):

You can make '4d' plot with `palette`, e.g:

```
splot '3d.dat' u 1:2:3:4 palette pt 9
```

Answer (score 1):

So you mean e.g. plotting a triedron `T(x,y,z=0)`, `T(x=0,y,z)` and `T(x,y=0,z)` ? This should be possible with `multiplot` and rotating the view between each plot. This will be a fair amount of hacking, so the first question would be why you don't use other visualization software like paraview or mayavi ? These are more suited for this type of data, unless you need the flexibility of gnuplot either in terms of scripting, or in terms of plotting analytical functions on the same graph.